# Syntax help - Convert Eregi_replace to preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, preg-replace, eregi

We just upgrade to PHP7 and the eregi function is now not working and I need to convert it to preg_replace. I've looked over a couple other topics which are requesting the same thing. I am having an issue with the syntax.

Current code

```
$body = eregi_replace("[\]", '', $body);
```

I've tried the following but it looks like it's not fully working as $body looks to be empty.

```
$body = preg_replace('[\]', '', $body);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You were trying to remove backslashes?

Comment: Use the regex `'/\\/'` or if you're just replacing a single character, `str_replace('\\', '', $body)` should be more efficient.

Comment: Don't say you weren't warned, these functions have been deprecated for many years.[

Comment: @Barmar okay I won't say I wasn't warned? Thanks?

Comment: @Sammitch thanks. I tried this instead and it worked great. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if `$body` is not empty

```
if($body!=null) {
$body = preg_replace('[\]', '', $body);

}
```